# Bad request when using sharepoint REST Service in angular js using ng-resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

I am using the ng-resource module to call rest services in my angular js app.  I based my angular js code in another one I used using the cross domain library for a sharepoint hosted app.

The old code was like this:

Now in my new angular js code looks like this:

**My ProductResource.js**

I had to use a substring because the app its a SPA and the routing adds a # at the end, so with that it also had a bad request, but I believe its better to remove it.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("productResource",
                ["$resource",
                 productResource]);

    function productResource($resource) {
        var listName = "Products";

        var n = SPAppWebUrl.indexOf("#");
        var resUrl = SPAppWebUrl.substring(0, n);


        // the url to use for the REST call.
        var url = resUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +

        // this is the location of the item in the parent web. This is the line
        // you would need to change to add filters, query the site etc
        //  "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?" +
            "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=Id,productName,productCode,releaseDate,description,cost,price,category,tags,imageUrl" +
            "&@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";

        //return $resource(url);
        //return $resource("/api/products/:productId")

        return $resource(url, {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET', 
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
            },
            create: { method: 'POST' }
        });
    }

}());
```

**ProductListCtrl, which uses the query method**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("productManagement")
        .controller("ProductListCtrl",
                    ["productResource",
                    ProductListCtrl]);

    function ProductListCtrl(productResource) {
        var vm = this;

        productResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.products = data;
        });

        vm.showImage = false;

        vm.toggleImage = function () {
            vm.showImage = !vm.showImage;
        }
    }
}());
```

and App.js which might not be relevant

```
var SPHostUrl;
var SPAppWebUrl;
var ready = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var param = params[i].split("=");
        switch (param[0]) {
            case "SPAppWebUrl":
                SPAppWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
            case "SPHostUrl":
                SPHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
        }
    }
});

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("productManagement",
                            ["common.services",
                             "ui.router",
                             "ui.mask",
                             "ui.bootstrap"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider",
                "$urlRouterProvider",
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

            $stateProvider
                .state("home", {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/welcomeView.html"
                })
                // Products
                .state("productList", {
                    url: "/products",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productListView.html",
                    controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
                })
                .state("productEdit", {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: "/products/edit/:productId",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditView.html",
                    controller: "ProductEditCtrl as vm",
                    resolve: {
                        productResource: "productResource",

                        product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                            var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                            return productResource.get({ productId: productId }).$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("productEdit.info", {
                    url: "/info",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditInfoView.html"
                })
                .state("productEdit.price", {
                    url: "/price",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditPriceView.html"
                })
                .state("productEdit.tags", {
                    url: "/tags",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditTagsView.html"
                })

                .state("productDetail", {
                    url: "/products/:productId",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productDetailView.html",
                    controller: "ProductDetailCtrl as vm",
                    resolve: {
                        productResource: "productResource",

                        product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                            var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                            return productResource.get({ productId: productId }).$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })

        }]
    );
}());
```

The error is bad request, but I cant find nothing wrong with the REST url.

"https://levalencia-00346f286827fc.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/CoreAngularJSCRUDSPList/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items?$select=Id,productName,productCode,releaseDate,description,cost,price,category,tags,imageUrl&@target='https://levalencia.sharepoint.com/sites/dev'"

See my console error here:

http://screencast.com/t/uxNh781s

Answer (score 0):

that is probably because you are sending problematic values on your request (such a https:// inside your url). try to modify your config file with like the following:

```
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
     <pages validateRequest="false"/>
```

Comment: encoding helps converting some characters to their proper url format.. but there are also other characters that are blocked for security reasons (like sql injections, etc). so, in that scenario the encoding woun't help - you need to turn off the mechanism in order to allow risky characters whenever they are encoded or not

Comment: this is a sharepoint hosted app. not a provider hosted app, so that means there is no web.config